# How to sort a MappedListIterable in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

I've got a `MappedListIterable` than I know to sort

When calling the sort method , I 'm getting

> EXCEPTION: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'MappedListIterable' has no
>   instance method 'sort'. Receiver: Instance of 'MappedListIterable'
>   Tried calling: sort(Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You get a `MappedListIterable` after calling [.map(f)](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) on an `Iterable`.

The [Iterable class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) does not have a `sort()` method. This method is on [List](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-core/List-class.html).

So you first need to get a `List` from your `MappedListIterable` by calling `.toList()` for example.

```
var i = [1, 3, 2].map((i) => i + 1);
// i is a MappedListIterable
// you can not call i.sort(...)

var l = i.toList();
l.sort(); // works
```

Or in one line (code-golf):

```
var i = [1, 3, 2].map((i) => i + 1).toList()..sort();
```

Comment: in one line ..sort works but why double dots? why not .sort? can you help me understand? or, please refer any documentation link.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447736/list-use-of-double-dot-in-dart/49447872#49447872 . `.sort()` returning `void` (sorting is done inplace) you can not assign the result to a variable.

Comment: When I do a toList() on my MappedListIterable, I get an error: Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'