# Delete elements by name from JSON?

Tags: json, dart

I am trying to drop elements from JSON. Here is my code:

```
String test = '[{
                 "type":"new",
                 "color":"red", 
                 "items": ["aa","bb", "cc"]
                }]';
var myJson = jsonDecode(test);
var result = myJson.where((a)=> a != 'items');
print(result);
```

It does not work. I need to drop `items` and get:
`[{"type":"new","color":"red"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSON, `test` array contains one object item with a property `items`. Thus, filtering is not caching it.
To remove items, you need to map over items and remove the items key from each.

UPDATED:

```
var result = myJson.map((a)=> {a.remove('items'); return a;} );
```

Comment: It should maybe also be added that the JSON is actually a list containing a Map.

Comment: @Eriks I am not sure about proper answer. Maybe it was small misunderstanding. I updated example to show what I need. Your current code print `([aa, bb, cc])`

Comment: @Eriks, that should be `m..remove`, not `m.remove`. Please add mention why.

Comment: @Eriks, but `myJson.map( (m) => m..remove('items') );` works too Could you explain difference between both approach?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447736/list-use-of-double-dot-in-dart two dots allow chaining of methods. In this case . and .. should be equivalent