# What is the ".." in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

While reading a tutorial online about how to fetch the device's location with Flutter, I see this code snippet:

```
final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
```

What is the `..` operator? I googled but couldn't find anything.

Full code from the tutorial:

```
  _getCurrentLocation() {
    final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;

    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's the cascade operator, so search for "dart cascade operator"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List use of double dot (.) in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447736/list-use-of-double-dot-in-dart)