# The argument type 'Colors.red' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Paint'

Tags: flutter

I want to set the background color red and I know that there is a 'backgroundColor' property under TextStyle widget, but I want to use background.

> I saw this code on another answer in other question but i dosent function to me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTTAi.png)

Comment: Need a little bit more information here, what are you trying to set the background of to red and can you provide some of your code where that widget you are trying to set the background of is?

Comment: Code works Fine in `TextStyle` - `background: Paint()..color = Colors.red` @Bryan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447736/list-use-of-double-dot-in-dart  this can help you have a better understanding of cascade notion. Paint()..color = Colors.red wil return the current Paint object. so your code works fine. the error hint may caused by something else.

Comment: The error is because of using const when trying to create _bigFont; and the actual error reads: " Cannot invoke a non-'const' factory where a const expression is expected."
So as I wrote below if you remove const keyword, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the screenshot is a screenshot of your actual code, then your problem is that you are using a const to initialise the Paint() constructor (which is a "non-const") which is why it is giving you an error.

So in your case just do this:

```
final _bigFont =   TextStyle(fontSize:18, background: Paint()..Colors.red);
```

And the error will go away.

Comment: It was not me :C